# How to setup nginx to host nodejs app with redirect to static page

Tags: nginx

I have added this config , but not sure how to fix it. I have node js app that running on this host `go.test.org` . I want to setup landing page `test.org` on softr to redirect to their IP. How to do it

```
// domain name test.org
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  server_name go.test.org test.org;

  return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}


server {
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    server_name go.test.org test.org;

   ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.org/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
   ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.org/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot

  // this seems to be not working , how to redirect from here ?
  if($host = test.org){
    return 301 43.234.12.098;
  }

  location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
    proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    proxy_redirect off;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

either use a different host , e.g.

```
server {
    server_name mydomain.example;
    return 301 http://www.adifferentdomain.example$request_uri;
}
```

OR

use a `map` statement

[You should not use the function](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/)  `if()`